# Extract only and all digits from a string

Tags: regex

I have a string composed of digits and other symbols, including spaces: exs. "123 456", "123-456", "123a456".

And I want to obtain only "123456" (I am using `pcre` engine).

I tried without success:

```
^\d+$
^[0-9]+$
^\s?([0-9\.]+)
```

Comment: normally \d should do the trick. Have you tried testing with https://regex101.com/ for example?

Comment: What tool / programming language are you using?

Comment: Just replace `\D+` with an empty string.

Comment: Note that `123456` is not actually any of the inputs.  Please explain.

Comment: I am using `Julia`. And when I try for ex. `match(r"\d+", "123 007")` I get only `123`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My input is `123 456` and the output should be `123456`.

Comment: What about the other two inputs?  Should they also match?

Comment: `replace(string1, r"\D+", "")`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes.

Comment: See the 3rd comment by @Wiktor

Comment: and my last one, too, it should work in Julia.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew   OK I think I got it finally in `Julia`: `replace("123 007", r"\D+" => "")`. The result is `123456`.

Comment: Great, the idea was just that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You can put it on an answer if you want.